# Bootstrap divs with spans less then 12 still taking up full row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I am brand new to bootstrap. I downloaded the precompiled bootstrap code right off the getting started tab of the bootstrap page. I saved the css, fonts, and js files in the same folder as my project. Within this folder I also included an index.html page. The index.html code file is shown below.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        .span12 {
            background: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .span6 {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px 0px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">Span 12</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">Span 6</div>
            <div class="span6">Span 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When this code runs the two divs with class span6 get displayed on different lines and each of them takes up a span of 12. I know that divs are typically displayed as block elements but I thought that by giving them a class of span6 and containing them within the same row div bootstrap would display them on the same line each taking up a span of 6.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the bootstrap 12 column grid to function differently from how I expected?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I believe it is v3.0.3. I just googled bootstrap and downloaded the newest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 3.0, Bootstrap no longer uses `span*` to determine the column-width of a div. Instead, use `col-XX-N`, where XX is "xs", "sm", "md", or lg", and N is the number of columns.

So, in your case, if you don't care about device responsiveness, replace `span6` with `col-xs-6`

See the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more